# How does vector not destroy element twice after reducing its size?

Tags: c++, resize, stdvector, destruction

For testing purposes, I was trying to create my own vector class, and I couldn't figure out how `std::vector` size reduction works.

```
class A
{
    A()
    { std::cout << "A constructed") << std::endl; }
    ~A()
    { std::cout << "A destroyed") << std::endl; }
}

main()
{
    std::vector<A> vec(3, A());
    vec.resize(2);
    std::cout << "vector resized" << std::endl;
}
```

Output is

```
A constructed       (1)
A constructed       (2)
A constructed       (3)
A destroyed         (1)
Vector resized
A destroyed         (2)
A destroyed         (3)
```

When `vec.resize(2)` is called, the third element is destroyed, but the vector's capacity is still 3. Then when `vec` is destroyed, all of its elements including the one already destroyed should be destroyed. How does `std::vector` know that he has already destroyed that element? How can I implement that in my vector class?

Comment: From your description, you have 3 constructor and 3 destructor. So, where is the problem? Size is a concept different from capacity

Comment: In other words, if you want to implement your own vector class, you need to track both `capacity` and `size`.

Comment: [See this home-made vector example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7ad7993f1251364).  Size and capacity are two different values.

Comment: Your `A` class does not take copy construction into account. You need a log message for the copy constructor, too: `A(const A &) { std::cout << "A copy constructed" << std::endl; }` There is a destructor call for each successful constructor call, whether that be the default constructor or the copy constructor. In `std::vector<A> vec(3, A());`, `A()` creates a temporary that is used to copy-construct the 3 elements, and then the temporary is destroyed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between capacity and size. Given a `std::vector<T> v;` The vector has allocated memory for `v.capacity()` elements. But only in the first `v.size()` places contain constructed `T` objects.

So, `v.reserve(1000)` on an empty vector won't call any additional constructors. `vec.resize(2)` in your example destroys the last element and `vec[2]` is now an empty place in memory, but memory still owned by the `vec`.

I think your allocation looks like `buffer = new T[newSize];`. That is not how `std::vector` works which would not allow `Ts` that do not have default constructors. Maybe you did not realize this, but whenever you obtain a piece of memory, it already contains objects, let it be `T x;` or even `new double[newSize];` which returns an array of doubles (although their constructors are empty).

There is only one way to get usable uninitialized memory in C++, which is to allocate `chars`. This is due to the [strict aliasing rule.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) There also (is|must be) a way how to call a constructor explicitly on this memory i.e. how to create an object there. The vector uses something called [placement new](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new) which does precisely that. The allocation is then simply `buffer = new char[newSize*sizeof(T)];` which creates no objects whatsoever.

The lifetime of the objects is managed by this placement new operator and explicit calls to destructors.
`emplace_back(arg1,arg2)` could be implemented as `{new(buffer + size) T(arg1,arg2);++size;}`. Note that simply doing `buffer[size]=T(arg1,arg2);` is incorrect and UB. `operator=` expects that the left size(`*this`) already exists.

If you want to destroy an object with e.g. `pop_back`, you must do
`buffer[size].~T();--size;`. This is one of the very few places where you should call the destructor explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that vector internally manages constructor and destructor calls, often by using inplace operator new and operator delete methods.

Having popped an element, it is immediately descructed, and while the memory is still available, and may still contain some remnant values, std::vector itself knows which elements still need to be deleted, and won't call the destructor again.

Answer (score 1):

> When `vec.resize(2)` is called, the third element is destroyed, but the vector's capacity is still 3.

Yes.  The `capacity` is how many elements the vector's internal array can physically hold.  The `size` is how many elements in that array are actually valid.  Shrinking the `size` does not affect the `capacity` at all.

> Then when `vec` is destroyed, all of its elements including the one already destroyed should be destroyed.

The 3rd element that was previously destroyed and removed from the array is not destroyed again.  Only `size` number of elements are destroyed, not `capacity` number of elements, like you are thinking.

> How does `std::vector` know that he has already destroyed that element?

It tracks the `size` and `capacity` separately.  When an element is removed from the array, the elements that follow it are moved down the array by 1 slot each, and the `size` is decremented.